# I can't install windows on my dell xps 15z

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation

The laptop was originally windows 7, but I decided to install Ubuntu over it. I now have a newer computer, so I gave it to my brother. He wants windows on it so he can play his games, but I'm having trouble installing windows on it.

I put the windows install disk in and try to reset pc, but I keep getting the error: Can't reset your PC. A required drive partition is missing.

I've gone into cmd and tried all of the bootrec commands; none of them work. I've tried going into diskpart, sel disk 0, sel vol 3 (my FAT32 partition), active. However, I keep getting the error: this partition isn't a fixed MBR disk.

I've also tried the cd /d c:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot command, but that doesn't work either. It says the requested path can't be found.

Any suggestions.

Also, ubuntu won't load anymore either. It says no operating system found when I boot to the drive instead of the cd.

Comment: Try deleting any extra partitions you may have created. When you are in the windows installer windows, you may see something like: Drive 0 : Partition 0, Drive 0 : Partition 1. Windows will prevent you from installing an OS on that partition unless all of the extra 'sub-partitions' have been deleted as well.

Comment: Do you still need Ubuntu? If not, then I would be happy to walk you through fully wiping your disk and rebuilding from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, but I've since found out what the issue is. I called dell, and it seems my laptop isn't compatible with windows 10 (at least that's what the support agent said). He sent me a bootable windows 7 thumb drive and I'm now up and running.

Answer (score -1):

If both windows and ubuntu are having issues with your HDD then there are either physical issues with it and it's broken or there are broken partitions (as suggested by the "Can't reset your PC. A required drive partition is missing" message). If you don't have anything important on the HDD then completely wipe it and try again, if you do have something important run a portable OS off a USB stick or DVD/CD and then make a copy of what's important (assuming it can be read). Ultimately it just sounds like it's time for a fresh start

Comment: What's the command to wipe it?

Comment: @Enesk from the windows 10 installer you can just delete all of the partitions and then create one big one and install it to that. I believe you need to do a custom windows 10 install, so not an upgrade, although i'm  letting a friend use my windows 10 installer to a friend so I can't verify that, If you can't get it done via you could try using "g-parted" from hiren's boot CD and use the partition editor. http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/ As for a command I wouldn't kow, I tend to avoid a command line as a GIU is more user freindly

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there is an option like that on the installer.

Comment: @Enesk I get my installation back today so I'll check it out when I get the chance

Comment: @Enesk when it gives you the options on how to install windows dont choose upgrade or install, use custom and then delete all of the partitions so there is just one unallocated partition. Select it and then click next so that windows will install. That should be all

Comment: I think I may have found my problem. The installation disk Dell gave me says BIOS needs to be set to UEFI mode before installation. My BIOS, however, doesn't have that option. Is there a way to update my BIOS without having an OS installed?

Comment: You can probably download it to a USB drive, I know I can do that with my 10 year MSI motherboard